# Leaflet webpage will not load

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to plot some lat-long points using the leaflet package for R using this function.

```
showWalk <- function(dt, walkNameStr) {
    dtOneWalk <- dt[walkNameStr == walkNameStr,]
    dtOneWalk$date <- as.POSIXct(dtOneWalk$time,origin="1970-01-01")

    leaflet(dtOneWalk) %>% addProviderTiles(provider = providers$Wikimedia) %>%
    addPolylines(lng=~dtOneWalk$long,lat=~dtOneWalk$lat) %>% 
    addCircles(color="red",popup=~paste(round(dist,3),"<br>",round(vel, 3),"<br>",date)) 
}
```

Every time I run it in R the console gives the statement "Assuming "long" and "lat" are longitude and latitude, respectively" then tries to open the webpage, but then about a minute later, the webpage gets an error. All I get is an Oops message on chrome and an Out of Memory message on Opera. On Firefox, I get the following result once I click debug the script :
[image]

The green highlighted part in the debug part was too long to post in the question.

Comment: You question lacks details mate. You need to provide more informations so people can help you. Print the whole error message in the OP as a start please...

Comment: I don't get an error message, which is the problem. RGui runs it fine, and Chrome's error message was pretty unhelpful. This is all the info I have basically.

Comment: Ok then. I won't waste your time. I can't help you. I used to work with leaflet with JavaScript. R is like Chinese to me. From what I remember with JS, when the map would print but the screen was not showing much, it was a scale problem... Some other times, (not related to your question though) my map tiles server was not loaded with the proper files or was rendering with scale problems... Be patient, this is stackoverflow, someone will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the scale problem, I think that solved it. I checked the points, and some of them are of the african cost when they're all supposed to be in the boston area, so I think drawing the lines between them all was too much work or something.